# Trying to access Postgres function from django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have a django app where I am trying to access some Postgres functions using django. I was following [this method](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/django_python_stored_procedures.aspx) to achieve this(though the database used in the site is mysql).

I was able to create the function successfully and it worked fine when i was trying it using sql commands.

This is how my model looks:

```
class Results(models.Model):
    test_type_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    test_id = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True, blank=True)
    test_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    YR = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    @staticmethod

    def summaryrosterbycampus(testtypeid, testid):
        cur = connection.cursor()
        cur.callproc('summaryrosterbycampus',[testtypeid, testid])
        results = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
        return [Results(*row) for row in results]
```

and i am trying to access this from the shell as follows:

```
>>> from reports.models import *
>>> data = Results.summaryrosterbycampus(request.GET[1,'201403MAME04'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'request' is not defined
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: `request` is available only when you have a web request/response. That is django adding it for you. It is not available in the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do stuff intended to be done in a view (which passes in a request object) in your shell (which doesn't have a request object).  I *think* you want something like:

```
exampleResult = Results.objects.all()[0] # or some other way to get a result to give you the test_type_id and test_id values to pass
data = Results.summaryrosterbycampus(exampleResult.test_type_id,exampleResult.test_id)
```

Comment: From the link you mentioned, note that he says "With the business end of this out of the way I can now perform searches in a view as follows:" and then does "results = Document.search(request.GET['search_string'])  "

Comment: all i want to do is access the function from django and pass the parameters. it worked when i did this in sql: """select * from summaryrosterbycampus(1,'201403MAME04');""" ...... so how do i pass parameters? is there another way of accessing functions?

Comment: data = Results.summaryrosterbycampus(1,'201403MAME04') should work

Comment: hi..your suggestion worked. But somehow the values i am getting are lists. Can i get the data as objects from the table?

Comment: You should be getting a list of Result objects.  Can you post an edit showing what 'print data' returns after the function call?